# Public MVC project using MSBuild not copying the global.asax file and i am getting error 404

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

When i am using the "Publish" button directly from the Visual Studio environment everything is working great. but when i am trying to publish using MSBuild command line, the global.asax file omitted and i am getting 404 Error when trying to access the site.

I suspect, but not sure, that when i am using MSBuild it uses the "precompiled" setting and i see the files App_global.asax.compiled file inside the BIN directory but the IIS ignores it.

if i have the file App_global.asax.compiled on the bin folder, is that mean that i don't need the global.asax file in the root directory? Why the IIS ignore the App_global.asax.compiled file and not loading the application?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Global.asax file and check `Build Action` in properties window. Ensure it is set to `Content`